# How to add a boxShadow to a Span Class if the Span Class Text = 1?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

not sure if this is the right place or not, but I'm trying to re-skin/theme/style a website for Chrome using Stylish or maybe Tampermonkey if it's not possible with html/css.

This is what the html part looks like that I'm trying to change:

```
<div class="queue-item thumb clickable ng-scope" ng-repeat="person in broadcasterService.queue" ng-click="goIfNotBroadcasting(loadChannel, person.userId)" once-style="{'background-image': 'url('+cdn.thumb+person.userId+'), url('+cdn.nothumb+')'}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-html-unsafe="<div class="user-row"><span class="ynicon ynicon-level"></span><span class="level">3</span> <span class="name">name</span></div><div class="viewer-row"><span class="ynicon ynicon-viewers"></span> <span class="viewers">344</span></div>"
```

More precisely `<span class="level">3</span>`
Basically what I'm trying to do is:

if span class="level" = 1 then boxShadow.

Already tried the following code with Tampermonkey but it's not working:

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("level")[1];
span.style.boxShadow="2px 2px 5px red";
```

and

```
var level = $(".queue-item.thumb.clickable.ng-scope span:contains('1')");
level.style.boxShadow="2px 2px 5px red";
```

Hope someone could help me out.

Thanks!

edit: Tried both the JQuery answers but it does not work. This is the straight up copy/paste from chromes inspect element console with the full div block or what ever its called:

```
<div id="tag-queue" ng-if="broadcasterService.queue.length &amp;&amp; !swf.settingUpBroadcast" class="ng-scope">
<div class="title ng-binding">
    148
    Broadcasters
    on 
    <span class="clickable ng-binding" ng-click="goIfNotBroadcasting(goto, 'explore/tag/'+broadcasterService.broadcaster.tags[0])">
                #girls
    </span>
</div>
<!-- ngRepeat: person in broadcasterService.queue --><div class="queue-item thumb clickable ng-scope" ng-repeat="person in broadcasterService.queue" ng-click="goIfNotBroadcasting(loadChannel, person.userId)" once-style="{'background-image': 'url('+cdn.thumb+person.userId+'), url('+cdn.nothumb+')'}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-html-unsafe="<div class=&quot;user-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-level&quot;></span><span class=&quot;level&quot;>69</span> <span class=&quot;name&quot;>MaddieWelborn</span></div><div class=&quot;viewer-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-viewers&quot;></span> <span class=&quot;viewers&quot;>635</span></div>" style="background-image: url(http://cdn2.younow.com/php/api/channel/getImage/channelId=2329157), url(http://cdn2.younow.com/images/nothumb.jpg);">
            <!-- ngIf: ::(broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==person.userId||broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==session.user.userId) -->
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: person in broadcasterService.queue --><div class="queue-item thumb clickable ng-scope" ng-repeat="person in broadcasterService.queue" ng-click="goIfNotBroadcasting(loadChannel, person.userId)" once-style="{'background-image': 'url('+cdn.thumb+person.userId+'), url('+cdn.nothumb+')'}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-html-unsafe="<div class=&quot;user-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-level&quot;></span><span class=&quot;level&quot;>30</span> <span class=&quot;name&quot;>RoosaMyllyla</span></div><div class=&quot;viewer-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-viewers&quot;></span> <span class=&quot;viewers&quot;>491</span></div>" style="background-image: url(http://cdn2.younow.com/php/api/channel/getImage/channelId=7068282), url(http://cdn2.younow.com/images/nothumb.jpg);">
            <!-- ngIf: ::(broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==person.userId||broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==session.user.userId) -->
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: person in broadcasterService.queue --><div class="queue-item thumb clickable ng-scope" ng-repeat="person in broadcasterService.queue" ng-click="goIfNotBroadcasting(loadChannel, person.userId)" once-style="{'background-image': 'url('+cdn.thumb+person.userId+'), url('+cdn.nothumb+')'}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-html-unsafe="<div class=&quot;user-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-level&quot;></span><span class=&quot;level&quot;>29</span> <span class=&quot;name&quot;>katieberryy_</span></div><div class=&quot;viewer-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-viewers&quot;></span> <span class=&quot;viewers&quot;>127</span></div>" style="background-image: url(http://cdn2.younow.com/php/api/channel/getImage/channelId=4851886), url(http://cdn2.younow.com/images/nothumb.jpg);">
            <!-- ngIf: ::(broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==person.userId||broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==session.user.userId) -->
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: person in broadcasterService.queue --><div class="queue-item thumb clickable ng-scope" ng-repeat="person in broadcasterService.queue" ng-click="goIfNotBroadcasting(loadChannel, person.userId)" once-style="{'background-image': 'url('+cdn.thumb+person.userId+'), url('+cdn.nothumb+')'}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-html-unsafe="<div class=&quot;user-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-level&quot;></span><span class=&quot;level&quot;>7</span> <span class=&quot;name&quot;>itsyourbaerose</span></div><div class=&quot;viewer-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-viewers&quot;></span> <span class=&quot;viewers&quot;>141</span></div>" style="background-image: url(http://cdn2.younow.com/php/api/channel/getImage/channelId=9443809), url(http://cdn2.younow.com/images/nothumb.jpg);">
            <!-- ngIf: ::(broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==person.userId||broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==session.user.userId) -->
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: person in broadcasterService.queue --><div class="queue-item thumb clickable ng-scope" ng-repeat="person in broadcasterService.queue" ng-click="goIfNotBroadcasting(loadChannel, person.userId)" once-style="{'background-image': 'url('+cdn.thumb+person.userId+'), url('+cdn.nothumb+')'}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-html-unsafe="<div class=&quot;user-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-level&quot;></span><span class=&quot;level&quot;>5</span> <span class=&quot;name&quot;>Larissaxo</span></div><div class=&quot;viewer-row&quot;><span class=&quot;ynicon ynicon-viewers&quot;></span> <span class=&quot;viewers&quot;>144</span></div>" style="background-image: url(http://cdn2.younow.com/php/api/channel/getImage/channelId=2403645), url(http://cdn2.younow.com/images/nothumb.jpg);">
            <!-- ngIf: ::(broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==person.userId||broadcasterService.broadcaster.userId==session.user.userId) -->
```

Comment: You appear to have a lot of HTML inside of a (non-standard and invalid) `tooltip-html-unsafe` attribute inside of an unclosed html element. Could you please check your posted HTML and ensure it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery (if you are able to) by doing something like this:

```
if ($('.level').html() == '1'){
    $('.queue-item').css({"box-shadow": "2px 2px 5px red"});
}
```

**[Here is an Example](https://jsfiddle.net/e9L60rfr/19/)**

Comment: Hmm not working for me. I edited my main post and posted the whole block straight from chromes inspect element console. Not sure if it changes anything from your answer or not or if I'm missing something in Tampermonkey.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to select all `.level` elements that have the `html()` your looking for:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $(".level").filter(function( index ) {
    return $(this).html() === '1';
  }).css( "boxShadow", "2px 2px 5px red" );
  
});
```

```css
.level{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="level">0</span>
<span class="level">1</span>
<span class="level">2</span>
<span class="level">3</span>
<span class="level">4</span>
<span class="level">5</span>
```

Comment: Hmm not working for me. I edited my main post and posted the whole block straight from chromes inspect element console. Not sure if it changes anything from your answer or not or if I'm missing something in Tampermonkey.

Comment: There are no elements in your example output with the class of 'level'. I only see it as a string within the `tooltip-html-unsafe` attribute. What I've given you answers the question posed (as you can see from the example) but I think the output you are presenting is AngularJS NOT final HTML. I think you should be looking for an AngularJS solution, or at the very least adding the `AngularJS` tag to your question so that it can be looked at by people familiar with it.